# PHP If shorthand

Tags: php

I would like to a simple if shorthand that check if an array has a particular key and if so unset it.

```
$test = array("hi" => "123");
isset($test["hi"]) ? unset($test["hi"]);
```

Why does this give a parse error? What is the correct syntax.

Comment: Ternary operator **IS NOT** a shorthand to `if`

Comment: I'm interested in why you don't want to use if's. Myself, I like them due to the fact that they make the code more easily read. Imagine someone else reading your code, like if you are having someone build on your project? Easily understood > less characters.

Comment: This example is actually pointless. There's no need to check a variable/index for existence before unsetting it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is a [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). This code:

```
$a = ($condition)? $b : $c;
```

is equivalent to:

```
if($condition) $a = $b;
else $a = $c;
```

For what you ask, there is no need for a check, you can simply `unset()` the array element without first checking it, and it would give no error messages:

```
unset($test["hi"]);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't use `unset()` in a [ternary conditional operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) as that language construct doesn't return a value, and the operator expects to evaluate to some value, not execute a code block. Plus, your ternary operator is incomplete (missing a `:` component).

How is an if statement that much longer anyway?

```
if (isset($test["hi"])) unset($test["hi"]);
```

Comment: As long as you've found new language feature - use it. Doesn't matter if it is useful or not - just use it, be modern ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The ternary conditional operator looks like this:

```
a ? b : c
```

You're missing that `c` clause, and your `b` clause is not an expression returning a value. This construct is **not** a shorthand for `if` statements and you are attempting to use it not for what it was designed.

Use an `if` statement:

```
if (isset($test['hi']))
    unset($test['hi']);
```

There's also the slightly more explicit [`array_key_exists`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php). Compare its documentation with that of `isset` to determine which is the more appropriate for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to test anything. If you try to unset a non-set variable, nothing happens.

The equivalent to your code would be:

```
$test = array("hi" => "123");
unset($test["hi"]);
```

Even if `$test["hi"]` isn't set, you can still unset it...

Comment: wouldn't any warning or notices crop up?

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = array("hi" => "123");
!isset($test["hi"]) ?: unset($test["hi"]);
```

Comment: Do you really think it is *better* than `if`?

Comment: The above will only work in PHP 5.3 I believe, as it is now possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. (Not suggesting that this is the *correct* approach, but merely from a syntax POV)

Comment: @Ross: It's still a syntax error because you can't use `unset()` in a ternary operator. See my answer.

Comment: @BoltClock clarified my comment - I was referring to using the syntax `?:`, but wasn't clear originally!